# Cannot access NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, object, dictionary, key

I created a JSON using a PHP script.
I am reading the JSON and can see that the data has been correctly read.
However, when it comes to access the objects I get unrecognized selector sent to instance...

Cannot seem to find why that is after too many hours. Any help would be great!

My code looks like that:

```
NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"raw json = %@,%@",json,error);  

NSMutableArray *name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[name addObjectsFromArray: [json objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

The code crashes when reaching the last line above.

The output like this:

```
raw json = (
        {
        category = vacancies;
        link = "http://blablabla.com";
        name = "name 111111";
        tagline = "tagline 111111";
    },
        {
        category = vacancies;
        link = "http://blobloblo.com";
        name = "name 222222222";
        tagline = "tagline 222222222";
    }
),(null)
2012-06-23 21:46:57.539 Wind expert[4302:15203] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdcfb970
```

HELP !!!

Comment: FYI, your first line of code will lead to a leak, unless you are using ARC. Either way, it is an unnecessary allocation.

Answer (score 2):

`json` is an array from what you've shown, not a dictionary. I can tell this because of the parentheses surrounding the whole of the log output for `json`. Inside the array are dictionaries, which I can tell by the fact that they are surrounded by braces.

So, it looks like you want something like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"raw json = %@,%@",json,error);  

NSMutableArray *name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *obj in json) {
    [name addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```

As an aside you will notice I have removed the unnecessary initialisation of `json` to an object before overwriting in the next line with `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`. In an ARC world it wouldn't be a leak but it's still completely unnecessary to allocate an object just to get rid of it again a moment later. Also I added in the `NSError *error = nil;` line since that was not there and was obviously necessary to compile.

Comment: @michaelblaize glad it solved it for you. I see you're new - so I'll point out that the idea is to accept by clicking the tick on the left of the answer you consider to be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that the root level of your JSON is an array, not a dictionary (note the parenthesis instead of curly brace as the first character in the logged output). Arrays do not have `objectForKey` selector. Perhaps you intend to take objectAtIndex:0 first, or else iterate over all the the items?

As an aside, the first line of your code makes a completely wasted initialization of an NSDictionary. It is simply overwritten and deallocated on the very next line.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is that actually a memory leak in an ARC project?

Comment: Indeed it's not a leak in an ARC project, which is what we should be canonically talking about these days.